# Imported module undefined during Debug

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm

I know this code is working.  But for whatever reason at times I'm not able to evaluate variables with WebStorm.

**PgMem.ts**

```js
import { newDb } from 'pg-mem';
import fs from 'fs';

const inMemoryDb = newDb();
inMemoryDb.public.none(fs.readFileSync('src/DB/pgMem/migrations/001-initial.sql', 'utf8'));
export default inMemoryDb;
```

**DBConnection.ts**

```js
import inMemoryDb from './pgMem/PgMem';
...

if (queryTypeId === queryType.MANY) {
  res = await inMemoryDb.public.many(query);
}
```

If I set a breakpoint on the line with `res` and it hits that breakpoint, `inMemoryDB` shows undefined during WebStorm debug.  I know that this code works without debugging so why would it say undefined if I try to use the evaluate tool or watch on that?

I thought when you import a module like that, it runs the code in the module that's imported so it already would have run `newDb();` and have an instance to work with which apparently it does, but just when I debug in WebStorm for this particular scenario, it's always undefined

Answer (score 1):

Undefined variables while debugging must be caused by wrong/missing name mappings in sourcemaps: if the variable is renamed while transpiling/obfuscating, and no appropriate name mapping is provided, the debugger won't be able to match variable in source code with the one in VM.

For example,
`import somefunction from './somefunc'` is usually compiled to

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var somefunc_1 = require("./somefunc");
somefunc_1.default();
```

and no name mappings are generated (`"names":[]` in generated sourcemap), so the debugger can't match the variable in `.ts` file with the code in runtime and shows `undefined`

Tickets that can be related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9627,  https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3957, https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/1468

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar scenarios. See if this helps

```
import {fs as fs} from 'fs';
```

something like this should avoid this issue while debugging